# mysql 5.7. GET_LOCK not working any more

Tags: php, mysql, apache

After upgrading to mysql 5.7 `GET_LOCK` stopped working as it used on mysql 5.5 and as I expected to work. I am aware of the changes regarding the `GET_LOCK` in 5.7. as described [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_get-lock).

When I execute the same script from the cmd line twice – with small pause in between –  it works as expected: First one acquires the lock and second one doesn't.

When I execute same php script via browser twice – with small pause in between – both return that they successfully acquired the lock. This result is not what I expected and it is different from version 5.5 and from my understanding of the `GET_LOCK` as described in 5.7 documentation.

- PHP is running as module (phpinfo() shows Server API: Apache 2.0
  Handler ).
- PHP version is: 7.0.20
- Mysql version is: 5.7.18 OS is
- CentOS 7.

This is the example script `locktest.php`:

```
<?php


$host = 'localhost';
$db   = 'enter_your_db';
$user = 'enter_your_username';
$pass = 'enter_your_password';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';


$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
    PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

echo "pid=(".getmypid().")\n";

$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT connection_id() as connid');
$row = $stmt->fetch();

echo "mysql connection id =(".$row['connid'].")\n";


$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT GET_LOCK("foobar", 2)');
$row = $stmt->fetch();


var_dump($row);
echo "\n\n";
sleep(10);
```

When this script is run from cmd line – I get what I expect:
Run php -q locktest.php from one terminal. Then immediately after from another terminal window.

The first one will return:

```
pid=(18378)
mysql connection id =(71)
array(1) {
  ["GET_LOCK("foobar", 2)"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

(please note that `GET_LOCK` result is 1)

The second one will return (started while the first one was still running):

```
pid=(18393)
mysql connection id =(73)
array(1) {
  ["GET_LOCK("foobar", 2)"]=>
  int(0)
}
```

(please note that `GET_LOCK` result is 0 – as expected, and different pid and mysql connection id).

When the same script is started twice from the browser – it reports that both scripts successfully obtained the lock.
First returns:

```
pid=(11913) mysql connection id =(74) array(1) { ["GET_LOCK("foobar", 2)"]=> int(1) }
```

Second returns (while first one is still running):

```
pid=(11913) mysql connection id =(75) array(1) { ["GET_LOCK("foobar", 2)"]=> int(1) }
```

Please note that pids are the same, but mysql connection id is different, and `GET_LOCK` result is not as expected since both returned 1.

Now I am confused. Different mysql connections (as returned by [CONNECTION_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_connection-id)) is used and this suggests different mysql sessions. And according to the mysql documentation it is possible to obtain more locks with same name from *SAME* session, but here I have different mysql sessions, right?

I even put `PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false` although that is a default value.

The only difference between output  from cmd line and browser are the pids (Different pids from two executed php scripts from cmd line, and same pids from two executed php scripts from the browser).

Any thoughts what is happening? For now, to me, it seems like a major issue since locking quietly stopped working. :(

Thanks.

Comment: Your lock timeout is only 2 seconds.  My guess is it's being freed by Mysql before the second request asks for the lock.  Try changing the lock timeout to 10 seconds or more.  If my guess is right I'll post it as an answer :)

Comment: Matt S - this is not the case. 

Please note sleep(10) at the end of the script - that means that the first script is locking for the 10s since I don't release the lock.

Lock timeout is deliberately set to be short, in order to provoke GET_LOCK to return 0 . 

So this is the timeline:
First script locks for 10 s.
Second scripts starts few seconds later: After 2 seconds GET_LOCK stops waiting (first script is still running with the obtained lock).

At this moment I expect the GET_LOCK from second script returns 0. As it returns from cmd line.

Comment: `GET_LOCK("foobar", 2)` will cause mysql to drop the lock automatically after 2 seconds. The script might sleep for 10 but the database will drop the lock after 2. If you set it to a much larger number you can test it's not timing out on the database side.

Comment: Matt S - no, it means that it waits for lock for 2s. After 2s it will return 1 on success or 0 on failure.
Lock will be released after RELEASE_LOCK() or after script terminates.

Comment: Oh ok.  My mistake.  Documentation doesn't make that clear.

Comment: Can you check the lock in the `\`performance_schema\`.\`metadata_locks\`` table?. See [25.11.12.1 The metadata_locks Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/metadata-locks-table.html).

Comment: You can also perform a quick test. Add [`RELEASE_ALL_LOCKS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_release-all-locks) function after `sleep(10);` and print the number of locks released.

Comment: @wchiquito I checked it. When executed from cmd line I have two entries. When executed from browser (apache php_mod) I have only one entry.
Also I increased the lock timeout to 15s and sleep to 50s in order to monitor the table. What surprised me that OWNER_THREAD_ID doesn't match with CONNECTION_ID() . Unfortunately  SO doesn't allow me to edit the post so here are metadata_locks entries: https://ibb.co/jqdxKk , https://ibb.co/mvia5Q .

Comment: @wchiquito I added `RELEASE_ALL_LOCKS()` . For cmd cli (which works correct) the script which obtained the lock returns 1, the other one returns 0. For apache php_mode (which doesn't work correct) both acquire the lock, and both return 1.

Comment: If it helps, `apachectl -M | grep php` returns `php7_module (shared)` and `apachectl -V | grep -i mpm` returns `Server MPM:     prefork`.

Comment: When execute from the command line you should get a single entry with the following values: `OBJECT_TYPE = 'USER LEVEL LOCK'` and `OBJECT_NAME = 'foobar'`. To get the correct `CONNECTION_ID` run: `USE performance_schema; SELECT CONNECTION_ID(), PROCESSLIST_ID FROM metadata_locks INNER JOIN threads ON OWNER_THREAD_ID = THREAD_ID WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'USER LEVEL LOCK' AND OBJECT_NAME = 'foobar';`.

Comment: The problem seems to be because the script (`locktest.php`) is not executed in parallel when launched from the browser, this means that the second script should wait for the first script to finish its execution. When the script (`locktest.php`) run from the command line, is executed in parallel. You can run the test and run `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` from MySQL to see the active connections.

Comment: Launch two requests from two different browsers, one request, for example, from Firefox and another request, for example, from Chrome.

Comment: @wchiquito In short, you were right, script was not executed in parallel when I started it from two tabs from the same browser. 
In more detail:
In order find out thread id I executed: `SELECT CONNECTION_ID() AS connid, performance_schema.threads.THREAD_ID AS thread_id FROM performance_schema.threads WHERE performance_schema.threads.PROCESSLIST_ID = CONNECTION_ID()` . 

With this info I was able to monitor running threads table: `select * from performance_schema.threads` and `metadata_locks` table.

Comment: @wchiquito Monitoring threads table proved that php script is executing one after another. At any given time there was only one entry in threads table.
When executing php script from cmd line or from different browsers I could see two entries in the threads table.

Also I updated php script to output the timestamp at the beginning and at the end. Output also proved that scripts are being executed one after another (although I "started" 2nd one, 1-2s after the 1st one). I don't really get why is this happening, but this is not an mysql `GET_LOCK()` issue.

Comment: @wchiquito since you comment was correct - do you want to make a comprehensive answer which I can accept?

Comment: @DamirR: [Bug #31464 session_start() function blocking the script](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=31464). The comment of the user `derick at php dot net` has the cause of the problem.

Comment: @wchiquito I didn't start session. I updated the script with call to [`session_status()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php) and it returns `PHP_SESSION_NONE`, also [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) returns empty string.
I would like to close (answer) this question since it was not a MySQL "bug" how I thought at the very beginning. Thank you for you helpful comments. :)